# Vb.net using mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm new to vb.net and mySQL and I'm trying to search the data in my database and now When I press the button4(search button) two times its getting an error (There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.)

```
 Dim con As New MySqlConnection("host=localhost; username=root; password=; database=pawnshop")
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click


    cmd.CommandText = " select clientid from clients where clientid= '" & txtId.Text & "'"

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Close()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM clients where clientid = '" & txtId.Text & "'"
        cmd.Connection = con
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.HasRows Then

            dr.Read()
            txtFname.Text = dr.Item("fname")
            txtMname.Text = dr.Item("mname")

        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Customer ID is not Found")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    dr.Close()
    cmd.CommandText = " select clientid from clients where clientid= '" & txtId.Text & "'"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Close()
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into pawn (clientid, category, type, gram, karat, date_added, description) values('" & txtId.Text & "','" & txtCategory.Text & "','" & txtType.Text & "','" & txtGram.Text & "','" & txtKarat.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker_DOB.Text & "','" & txtDesc.Text & "')"
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        MsgBox("Successfully Added")

    Else
        MsgBox("Customer ID not Found")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmExisting_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
End Sub
```

Comment: After you've finished reading data from a `DataReader`, you should close it with `dr.Close()` - better still, if you use a `using` block, the `DataReader` will be closed and disposed for you. On an aside, I'm really not sure what that first `DataReader` is doing for you - you seem to just be opening and closing it without using it, and the second one has the same where clause anyway.

Comment: You are not closing or disposing of any of the Data Provider objects, but you appear to reuse the same connection over and over.